# mysql group and filter results

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 queries!

```
select LINE, ACCOUNT
from DATAS
where date between "2015-07-01" and "2015-07-15" 
and SIG="in"
group by ACCOUNT
order by ACCOUNT
```

and

```
select LINE, ACCOUNT
from DATAS
where date between "2015-07-01" and "2015-07-15" 
and SIG="out"
group by ACCOUNT
order by ACCOUNT
```

Sample results:

```
LINE-ACCOUNT, SIG
0-1309  IN
0-1331  IN
0-1340  IN
0-1361  IN
0-1404  IN
0-1555  IN

LINE-ACCOUNT, SIG
0-1098  OUT
0-1309  OUT
0-1322  OUT
0-1331  OUT
0-1340  OUT
0-1555  OUT
```

I want 2 queries that will give that results:

1. Give me the ACCOUNTs that have "in" sign, but it hasn't "out" sign!
2. Give me the ACCOUNTs that have "out" sign, but it hasn't "in" sign!

I solved it in excel, but it is too complicated to solve it day by day! ;)

if it is easier I accept the solution in php too!

I hope you understand what I want!

thanks in advance

Comment: some sample data & expected results might help here - can account have multiples INs & OUTs?

Comment: LINE-ACCOUNT, SIG
0-1309 IN
0-1331 IN
0-1340 IN
0-1361 IN
0-1404 IN
0-1555 IN

LINE-ACCOUNT, SIG
0-1098 OUT
0-1309 OUT
0-1322 OUT
0-1331 OUT
0-1340 OUT
0-1555 OUT

Comment: You have 2 queries that accomplish your result, don't you?

Comment: My queries is not good, because i need to union, group and rearrange the  2 queries in excel for the good results... I want to exclude the wrong accounts like 0-1309, 0-1331, 0-1340, 0-1555 in my results!
did you think of this?

Comment: A great rule-of-thumb is 'never have a GROUP BY clause without an aggregate function and (almost) vice versa' - oh and 'never include an unaggregated column in the SELECT clause that isn't also included in the GROUP BY clause'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
select * from 
(
    (select LINE, ACCOUNT, SIG
    from DATAS
    where date between "2015-07-01" and "2015-07-15" 
    and SIG="in"
    group by ACCOUNT
    order by ACCOUNT)
    union all
    (select LINE, ACCOUNT, SIG
    from DATAS
    where date between "2015-07-01" and "2015-07-15" 
    and SIG="out"
    group by ACCOUNT
    order by ACCOUNT)
) t1
group by LINE, ACCOUNT
having count(Line) = 1
```

EDIT:Corrected the query

EDIT: Here's a brief explanation on how the query works. First off, we select every line that has SIG = 'IN'... then we append every line that has SIG = 'OUT'.

Now is where it gets interesting. If a line has both an IN and an OUT statement, it'll appear twice in our current resultset because it'll be part of both the SIG = "IN" and SIG = "OUT" query. On the other hand, a line that only has an "IN" or an "OUT" will only appear in one of the two inner query. We're going to take advantage of this.

The outer select statement with its "group by LINE, ACCOUNT" statement flattens our resultset and thus allows us to use the count() function. If a line appears in both queries, the count() will equal two... on the other hand, if a line appears only in one of the two queries, the count() will equal one. Those are the lines we want.

Still, in SQL, you can't do:

```
select * from table where count() > 1
```

If you want to place a condition using an aggregate function, you have to use the "having" clause, which is placed after a "group by" statement and acts exactly like a "where", only with an aggregate function.

Comment: Wouldn't that give results where an account has both IN & OUT values, OP wants to find those that have an IN with no OUT & vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the query, I believe this solution will work now, unless an account can have multiple out/in statements. In which case, you'd need to add a level to flatten them out.

Comment: I have error: 
"Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY "

Comment: I've added a set of parenthesis around each of the two union query. Try that and see if that corrects the bug

Comment: Thanks it is works now, but I see a lot of datas!
I would like to separate, which one is with only "IN" and which one is with only "OUT"
e.g.: I want two colums 1 name of column: "NO IN" 2. name of columns: "NO OUT"
I hope it is clear... ;)

Comment: Just add the SIG column to the two inner selects and with that, you'll instantly see if the line is an "IN" or an "OUT" since the outer query takes only lines that appear once.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the solution!
1 question yet:
What is the explain of the last row (having count(Line) = 1)
What is it doing?

Comment: I added a detailed explanation in my post that should answer your question. If anything's not clear, don't hesitate to ask ;)